# How to make a button a string variable and use it in an if statement

Tags: java, button, dialog, joptionpane

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");

  Object[] options = {
    "Dice roll",
    "Magic 8 ball"
  };

  int a1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
    "Would you like to roll the dice " + "or use the Magic 8 ball?",
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    options,
    options[1]);

  if (a1 != 0) {
    Object[] options = {
      "Dice roll", // error
      ""
    };

    int a2d = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, // error
      "do you want dice roll 1 " + "or dice roll 2?",
      JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
      null,
      options,
      options[1]);
  }
}
```

I want it so that the window with the buttons will be a variable that i can use in 
if statements but if i copy the code and change the buttons it says that the "Object[] options" is already defined as a variable and the variable "int a2d" is an error.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking, but you can't use the same variable name twice in the same scope. AKA you can't do `Object[] options;` and then another `Object[] options;`

Comment: What would i need to change for it to let me use the options.

Comment: Improved code formatting